# How to static linking to glibc in cmake

Tags: cmake, static-linking, software-packaging

I'm trying to build a package from Fedora that can run on a RedHat 6 machine. So I need to build and static linking with some library that does not exist in RedHat machine.

I found that I can you `-static-libgcc` or `-static-libstdc++` to link with static version of standard library but I don't know how to do with `glibc`.

How can I link to static library of `glibc` with CMake?

Answer (score 13):

I know the question mentions `glibc` but for C++, since `-static-libgcc` and `-static-libstdc++` are linker options, the correct way to set them in CMake is with [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html).

So you would set it like this, where MyLibrary is the name of your project:

```
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary -static-libgcc -static-libstdc++)
```

Given this, if you want complete static linking of `glibc` you would likewise pass the `-static` flag.

```
target_link_libraries(MyLibrary -static)
```

If you want more of a global setting:

```
set(BUILD_SHARED_LIBS OFF)
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "-static")
```

However, bear in mind that `glibc` is not designed to be statically linked, and without a great amount of additional work, you won't wind up with a truly static package. Your use case of building "a package from Fedora that can run on a RedHat 6 machine" will not readily work by statically linking `glibc`.

Comment: This does not answer the question, does it? The question is about linking glibc statically, and the answer explains how to link libgcc and libstdc++ statically...

Comment: My answer does now.

Comment: Thanks for the edit :). Good point about glibc not being designed to be statically linked, too! Finally I would like to mention musl that may be a viable alternative depending on the use-case